# From Textarea to multiple value insert using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am struggling with my PDO insert into a database from a textarea which contains information like this:

user1|pass1
user2|pass2
user3|pass3

The current problem is that the LAST account of this list gets inserted into my DB multiple times, but I can't figure it why this is happening. This is my Code:

```
// Divide the textarea by line into a string array
$accounts = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['accountData']);

// Prepare the Query
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, referral, dateCreated,region,idOrder) VALUES ";
// Create the multiple value placeholder
$qPart = array_fill(0, sizeof($accounts), "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query .= implode(",",$qPart);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$idOrder=100;

switch($priority)
{
    case("low"):
        $date="2050-01-01 00:00:00.000";
        $i = 1;
        foreach($accounts as $item){
            list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item);
            echo $user . ":" . $pass . "<br>";
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $user);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $pass);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $refid);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $date);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $region);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $idOrder);
        }
    break;

    case("high"):
        $date="2000-01-01 00:00:00.000";
        foreach($accounts as $item){
            list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item);
            echo $user . ":" . $pass . "<br>";
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $user);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $pass);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $refid);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $date);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $region);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $idOrder);
        }
    break;
}
$stmt->execute();
```

I echod $user and $pass and it showed the right user:pass (= 3 different users and passwords). But in the DB only the LAST user got inserted multiple times. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding the parameters / variable names and not the values.

Now, when you execute the statement, the current value of the parameters will be used and these are the values from the last iteration of your loop.

Instead of `bindParam` you should use [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).